# how to deploy "vosao" CMS web on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, content-management-system

I am trying to to deploy `VOSAO CMS` web on google app engine for java application, but when I goes to deploy this its showing an exception that is-

> C:\appengine\bin>appcfg.cmd update c:\vosaocms\
>
> ---
>
> ### There is a new version of the SDK available.
>
> ### Latest SDK: Release: 1.5.2 Timestamp: Wed Jun 22 13:51:46 IST 2011 API versions: [1.0]
>
> Your SDK: Release: 1.5.1 Timestamp: Wed Jun 15 06:46:40
>   IST 2011 API versions: [1.0]
>
> ---
>
> Please visit http://code.google.com/appengine for the
>   latest SDK.
>   ******************************************************** Reading
>   application configuration data...
>
> Jul 25, 2011 7:42:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
>
> readAppEngineWebXml
>
> INFO: Successfully processed c:/vosaocms\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>
> Jul 25, 2011 7:42:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRead erreadConfigXml
>
> INFO: Successfully processed c:/vosaocms\WEB-INF/web.xml
>
> Beginning server interaction for gwt-dev-plugin-missing...
>
> 0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\LocalTempappcfg3462929991524270004.tmp'
>
> 5% Scanning for jsp files.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found a file too large to upload:"C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3462929991524270004.tmp\vosaocms-0.8.war".
>
> Must be under 10000000 bytes. Unable to update app: Found a file too large to upload: "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3462929991524270004.tmp\vosaocms-0.8.war".  Must be
>    under 1000000 0 bytes.
>
> Please see the logs [C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg5840016530580965639.l og] for further information.

How can I solve this problem.Thx.

Answer (score 1):

After unpack war file delete this war file form that place and try this it will work.